# How to start download immediately (but can't chunk data)?

Tags: python, django

I have a view like this:

```
def download(request):
    response = StreamingHttpResponse([save_virtual_workbook(make_xl_workbook())], content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
    response[u'Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
    return response
```

But it waits to prompt the user to download until after make_xl_workbook has run.

I was reading that I can't chunk out the data returned from make_xl_workbook because xlsx files are zipped.  So I was hoping to start the download right away, then run the function and then pump the full data into the response once that function has run.

I also tried this but it didn't seem to help.  It still runs the full function make_xl_workbook before the download starts.

```
def download(request):
    def save_xl():
        yield save_virtual_workbook(make_xl_workbook())
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(save_xl(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
    response[u'Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
    return response
```

Update: Also tried this and got the same behavior, no change.

```
def download(request):
    def save_xl():
        yield ''
        yield save_virtual_workbook(make_xl_workbook())
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(save_xl(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
    response[u'Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
    return response
```

Comment: I think it should be enough to yield (an empty string?) once before the `yield save_virtual_workbook(...)`

Comment: If you have to create the file ahead of time, and that's the major bottle-neck, do you really save that much by having it start to download first?

Comment: @Jiaaro, thanks, but just tried it and no improvement.